# Meaning of "players" and "port of a bitt"

Tags: definition, french

The [Cotgrave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randle_Cotgrave) *Dictionarie of the French and English Tongues* (1611) has this definition for the word *Babillon*:

> **Babillon: m. The players that hang to the port of a bitt.**

Can anyone shed some light about what **bitt** means here?

Can it be that [bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_(horse)) (horse)? or something else related to a beard as I suspect the French word is a variant or a typo for *barbillon*?

What **players** might this be about?

---

[image: Cotgrave definition]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> II. That which plays.
>  ✝6. A metal pendant to a horse's bit.
> *Obs.*
> **1598** FLORIO, *Saliutra*,.. among riders the plate whereat the players that hang in the mids of a port are fastned. **1607** MARKHAM
> *Caval. VI*. (1617) 57 He shall haue Snaffles of all shapes..with small rings in the midst, and sundry sort of small players fastned to
> those ringes, which to a trauel- ling horse breedes pleasure. **1611**
> COTGR., *Babillons*, the players that hang to the port of a bitt.
>
> [ NED/OED1, ["*player*"](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/978/mode/1up) ]

So those are "[loosely attached thin plates in the center of the mouthpiece [of a horse], for example](https://horsebyhorse.com/blogs/news/the-purpose-of-the-bit-and-common-misconceptions)", also called *key bits*, and are/were used for mouthing and increased salivation. A [*ported mouthpiece*](https://www.horsesaddleshop.com/horbitter.html) has a curve in the middle. So the former is attached to the latter. Can't find an exact image for both but consider this [antique breaking bit with keys](http://www.sportingcollection.com/bits/bit100/bit100.html) ("A wire loose ring straight bar snaffle with three players or keys"):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bitt) defines bitt as

> a post or pair of posts fixed on the deck of a ship for securing lines

If you google "bitt images" you will find plenty of pictures of them.

**port** is the left-hand side of a ship when facing forwards, so "to the port of a bitt" means on the left hand side of a post that you attach ropes to.

I can't find any references to player, but I would guess that it is something to do with ropes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the actual meaning thanks to the OED1:

> **Player**
> ...
> II. That which plays.
> ✝ **6.** A metal pendant to a horse's bit. *Obs.*
> **1598** Florio, *Saliuéra*,..among riders the plate whereat the players that hang in the mids of a port are fastned. **1607** Markham *Caval.* VI. (1617) 57 He shall haue Snaffles of all shapes..with small rings in the midst, and sundry sort of small players fastned to those ringes, which a traueling horse breedes pleasure. **1611** Cotgr. *Babillons*, the players that hang to the port of a bitt.

So *Bitt* is an old spelling for a horse *bit*, *port* the part of the bit located in the horse mouth, possibly its curved center, and *players* are metallic thingies hanging to the port designed to "entertain" the horse and make it drool.